# MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error:Too many output arguments; from Matlab to C#

Tags: c#, matlab

when `c#` call the function from `Matlab` based `dll`.

**it shows the error:**

> System.Exception MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error too many output
>   arguments.

`matlab2014a`,`vs2013`, `.net4.0`.
the code works well in matlab2014a, but when calling it in vs `c#`: error

```matlab
function [stren MU] = stre(year, month,day, minute,x1,y1,x2,y2,sun,p,g,f)
```

```cs
s.Class1 sc = new s.Class1();
sc.stre(2010,4,11,1,0,34.27.108.88,33.22,120.33,20,0,0,18);
```

but I haven't accepted the output arguments stren and MU, they are both the array of 24 number.